# ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Tags: mysql, mysqlconnector

He creado la siguiente tabla en la base de datos "oscars":

```
create table peliculas(
    idPelicula int auto_increment, 
    tituloPelicula varchar(100), 
    anioPelicula decimal(4,0), 
    generoPelicula varchar(25), 
    nacionalidadPelicula varchar(45), 
    numeroOscarsPelicula int, 
    directorPelicula varchar(60), 
    primary key(idPelicula)
);
```

He creado también una función que devuelve el número medio de estatuillas ganadas entre todas las películas:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION funcion_MediaOscars()
RETURNS DECIMAL(4,2) READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE media_Oscars DECIMAL(4,2);
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT AVG(numeroOscarsPelicula) FROM peliculas;
OPEN cursor1;
FETCH cursor1 INTO media_Oscars;
CLOSE cursor1;
RETURN media_Oscars;
END //
```

Ahora tengo que usar la función anterior para crear un procedimiento que devuelva las películas con un número mayor de estatuillas que la media (utilizando otro cursor obligatoriamente). Esto el lo que he hecho:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE procedimiento_MasMedia ()
BEGIN
DECLARE sobreMedia text;
DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT tituloPelicula FROM peliculas WHERE numeroOscarsPelicula > (SELECT 
funcion_MediaOscars());
OPEN cursor2;
vuelta : LOOP
FETCH cursor2 INTO sobreMedia;
IF contador = 1 THEN LEAVE vuelta;
END IF;
SELECT sobreMedia AS 'Películas con más Oscars que la media';
END LOOP vuelta;
CLOSE cursor2;
END //
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando llamo a este procedimiento me sale el siguiente error:

> ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or
> processed

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a corregirlo?

Comment: Cuesta trabajo leer el código, recomiendo que lo indentes correctamente

Comment: ya se lo idente, otra cosa segun entiendo en este post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555933/4717133 debes definir un handler de continuidad para cuando sea 0.

Comment: No edites tu pregunta para agregar la solución que encontraste: ¡puedes [responder a tu propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al comentario de Francisco Núñez lo he solucionado. Había que declarar un HANDLER de salida cuando contador es igual a 0.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE procedimiento_MasMedia ()
BEGIN
DECLARE sobreMedia text;
DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT tituloPelicula FROM peliculas WHERE numeroOscarsPelicula > (SELECT 
funcion_MediaOscars());

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET contador = 0;

OPEN cursor2;
vuelta : LOOP
FETCH cursor2 INTO sobreMedia;
IF contador = 1 THEN LEAVE vuelta;
END IF;
SELECT sobreMedia AS 'Películas con más Oscars que la media';
END LOOP vuelta;
CLOSE cursor2;
END //
```